# What does the phrase "badly lit" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases

What is the meaning of the phrase "badly lit" in the following scene from the TV series [Columbo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Columbo) (emphasis mine):

> [*Set in a court of law. Prosecution is attempting to prove their
>   client was injured falling down some stairs because they did not have
>   adequate lighting.*]
>
> *Prosecution Lawyer*: The plaintiff alleges the stairs were ***badly
>   lit***.
>
> *Defence Lawyer*: Although the plaintiff may well have been!
>
> (Laughter all around)

It seems from the context that the phrase is being used to mean "drunk". If so, is this a common use. I've certainly never heard it before.

Comment: In grabbing references for my answer, I realized this is a general reference question.

Comment: Why do you think that Jim? It's certainly not blindingly obvious. Unless of course I'd just never heard it because it's an American phrase.

Comment: @Urbycoz 'General reference' doesn't mean obvious, it means you can answer the question easily by googling it. I don't think that fits in this case because there is the pun to explain.

Comment: @Jeremy Ok, but I did Google the phrase "badly lit", and saw no mentions of an interpretation meaning "drunk". http://www.google.co.uk/search?source=ig&hl=en&rlz=&q=badly+lit&oq=badly+lit&aq=f&aqi=g1g-v7g-b2&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=334l334l0l958l1l1l0l0l0l0l257l257l2-1l1l0

Comment: @Jeremy The more common use of lit (referring to the stairs) seems to be well understood in this case. Simply looking up the definition of lit yields the other meaning, at which point the pun is easily understandable.

Comment: @Jim You're missing the point, I'm afraid. I was looking up the phrase "badly lit", and could not see any mention of it meaning drunk. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44482/what-does-the-phrase-badly-lit-mean

Comment: @Urbycoz Hm...yes, searching for "badly lit" rather than "lit" would certainly make a difference. Wish I could unflag.

Comment: @Jeremy (and others who make this same mistake), "general reference" ***doesn't*** mean "you can answer the question easily by googling it"!! It means "you can easily find the answer in a reference work *designed to answer that type of question*" - a dictionary for a word meaning, a thesaurus for synonyms, an etymological dictionary for word/phrase origins.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lit is the past tense of light. It means that the stairs did not have good lighting (or more specifically, the person who set up the lighting on the stairs did a bad job.)

The joke is a pun that comes from the fact that lit or lit up can also mean drunk.

Comment: It also encorporates the word "badly". It means "not very well" when refering to the actual lighting, and "in extreme" when refering to the drunkenness.

Answer (score 2):

It is sometimes used to mean drunk or intoxicated, defined [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lit).

> : affected by alcohol : drunk

It is also sometimes used to describe someone as under the influence of marijuana<sup>[ref](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=lit)</sup>.

Comment: ...or harder drugs. Take the Buckcherry song *Lit Up*, which explicitly mentions Cocaine.